# About ui buttons in unity with conditions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Problem with unity UI buttons with conditions

attempt to replace the keys with buttons

```c#
void SlashAttack () 
{
    // We look for the current state looking at the information of the animator
    AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo = anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0);
    bool loading = stateInfo.IsName("Player_Slash");

    // Ataque a distancia
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("p") || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z))
    { 
        anim.SetTrigger("loading");
        aura.AuraStart();
    } 
    else if (Input.GetKeyUp("p") || Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Z))
    { 
        anim.SetTrigger("attacking");
        if (aura.IsLoaded()) 
        {
            // Para que se mueva desde el principio tenemos que asignar un
            // valor inicial al movX o movY en el edtitor distinto a cero
            float angle = Mathf.Atan2(anim.GetFloat("movY"), anim.GetFloat("movX")) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

            GameObject slashObj = Instantiate(slashPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward));

            Slash slash = slashObj.GetComponent<Slash>();
            slash.mov.x = anim.GetFloat("movX");
            slash.mov.y = anim.GetFloat("movY");
        }

        aura.AuraStop();
        StartCoroutine(EnableMovementAfter(0.4f));
    } 

    // Prevenimos el movimiento mientras cargamos
    if (loading) 
    { 
        movePrevent = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How can I replace the "p" key with buttons?

Comment: without affecting my conditions

Comment: fisrt off move the functionality to seperate methods, it will become pretty obvious once you do that

Answer (score 1):

Fast response: You can't because `UI.Button` doesn't have any callbacks for something like `button down` or `button up`

---

You can write your own component using [IPointerDownHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerDownHandler.html) and [IPointerUpHandler](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerUpHandler.html) if you really don't want to change your current code structure e.g. like

```c#
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class Example : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{
    public bool isDown;
    public bool isUp;

    //Detect current clicks on the GameObject (the one with the script attached)
    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        isDown = true;
    }

    //Detect if clicks are no longer registering
    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
    {
        isUp = true;
    }

    // reset both in LateUpdate
    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        isDown = false;
        isUp = false;
    }
}
```

Attach this to your buttons.

Than in your code reference according component

```c#
public Example PButton;

void SlashAttack () 
{
    // ...

    // Ataque a distancia
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("p") || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z) || PButton.isDown)
    { 
        // ...
    } 
    else if (Input.GetKeyUp("p") || Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Z) || PButton.isUp)
    { 
        // ...
    } 

    // ...
}
```

**Note**

> Ensure an `EventSystem` exists in the Scene to allow pointer detection. For pointer detection on **non-UI** GameObjects, ensure a `PhysicsRaycaster` is attached to the Camera.

Comment: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
Player.SlashAttack () (at Assets/Scripts/Player.cs:126)
Player.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Player.cs:56)

Comment: did you reference somthing in `PButton`?

Comment: well, than you should try to do so ;) simply drag and drop the according component into the field in the inspector

Comment: Would you mind tell the exact line (code not the number) where this occures?

Comment: okay i have you class Example, implements in my ui button and this lane have the problem "   if (Input.GetKeyDown("p") || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z) || PButton.isDown)"

Comment: is because PButton.isDown

Comment: Than as mentioned before you haven't referenced `PButton` properly e.g. via drag&drop in the Inspector or if it is instantiated later via script.

Answer (score 0):

First off seperate functionality into seperate methods, for example:

```c#
public void OnKeyDown()
{
     anim.SetTrigger("loading");
     aura.AuraStart();
}

public void OnKeyUp()
{
    anim.SetTrigger("attacking");
    if (aura.IsLoaded()) 
    {
        // Para que se mueva desde el principio tenemos que asignar un
        // valor inicial al movX o movY en el edtitor distinto a cero
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(anim.GetFloat("movY"), anim.GetFloat("movX")) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;

        GameObject slashObj = Instantiate(slashPrefab, transform.position, Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward));

        Slash slash = slashObj.GetComponent<Slash>();
        slash.mov.x = anim.GetFloat("movX");
        slash.mov.y = anim.GetFloat("movY");
    }

    aura.AuraStop();
    StartCoroutine(EnableMovementAfter(0.4f));
}

void SlashAttack () 
{
    // We look for the current state looking at the information of the animator
    AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo = anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0);
    bool loading = stateInfo.IsName("Player_Slash");

    // Ataque a distancia
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("p") || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z))
    { 
       OnKeyDown();
    } 
    else if (Input.GetKeyUp("p") || Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Z))
    { 
        OnKeyUp();
    } 

    // Prevenimos el movimiento mientras cargamos
    if (loading) 
    { 
        movePrevent = true;
    }
}
```

As we made the methods public, you can now link them to the UI. Because standard unity button only supports click, and your code is depenedent on button release, you could use EventTrigger component to bring out the events you want to link to

[image]